# Why is this heuristic admissible?

Tags: algorithm, heuristics

For Tic Tac Toe my lecturer has presented an admissible heuristic (meaning it never overestimates the distance) for the next move in Tic Tac Toe as follows (from the perspective of the O player):

> The number of possible lines for O - the number possible lines for X

What I was wondering is why is this heuristic admissible?

Comment: well, at a minimum, player X (to win) must make the # possible lines for X > the number possible lines for O. Otherwise the game is not ended in an X victory, correct? As such, the number of lines that they differ by is admissible because at LEAST that distance must be made up for an X victory

Comment: It's definitely not if an admissible function should be `<= 0` at the goal. A lot of material seems to say it should be = 0.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't know. That seems like not a real requirement. Also, a consistent heuristic is an admissible one. A CH never backtracks it's estimate (cost of getting to goal is <= getting to state S and the estimate from S). That seems to be quite true for this case: you can't open up new avenues in a TTT game, can you?

Comment: You could just change it to `if (at goal) 0 else {what you wrote}` for the `=0` thing to hold. What goal are we talking about though? `O` winning? `X` winning? Either? See my answer below for why it might not be admissible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not.

```
O..
XOX
OX.
```

Then distance to goal = (3-1) = 2

Actual distance to goal, 1 (for win by `O`)

2 > 1, thus it overestimated.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: well, this board isn't possible from O's point of view, right?

Comment: i don't know, you've started making me doubt myself for sure, but i can't convince myself that it is not admissible from what's here alone

Comment: "for the next move" - I think I missed that part.

Comment: Edited for a board state with `O` to move.

Comment: I'm sort of stumped then. Can you see where the flaw in my consistent heuristic comment is? because CH => AH, and to me (from the definition of a CH), this seems pretty monotonic...

Comment: @AK4749 You seem to not have considered `O`'s victory, and number of lines isn't a measure of winning, just a decent strategy (consider a player running up the side, he'll win but never have the most lines).

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic):

> a heuristic function is said to be **admissible** if it never overestimates the cost of reaching the goal

What that basically means, is that when you have a heuristic, this will only be admissible if the actual cost to the goal is guaranteed higher than or equal to the estimated cost. A good example for this is a heuristic for the A* path finding algorithm. For that algorithm, you usually use a heuristic that estimates the distance to the target like there is a road directly to it. If you would use a heuristic that would overestimate the distance, it it might not find the shortest possible path.